# How can I restart this game using the button at the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codepen

I'm trying to make a simple snake game and so far most of it works, except restarting the game after the user has failed. I've added a button to the top and I'm hoping that a user can click the button to restart the game.

Here is the HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Snake</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="restart" value="restart" style="font: normal 30px 
monospace; color: white; background-color: blue;">Restart</input>
<h1 id="score" style="font: normal 50px monospace; color: white;">Score: 
</h1>
</body>
```

the CSS

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: black;
}
td{
width: 20px;
 height: 20px;

}

.blank{
 background-color: blank;
}

.snake{
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.wall{
background-color: #cf1020;
}

.fruit{
background-color: gold;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The javaScript

```
//settings 
var snakeX = 2; 
var snakeY = 2; 
var height = 28; 
var width = 50; 
var interval = 100; 
var increment = 1; 

//game variables 
var length = 0; 
var tailX = [snakeX]; 
var tailY = [snakeY]; 
var fX; 
var fY; 
var running = false; 
var gameOver = false; 
var direction = -1; // up = 0, down = -1, left = 1, right = 2 
var int; 
var score = 0; 
//temporary direction (this fixes users pressing keys too quickly and 
turning into themselves) 
var tempdir = direction; 

/** 
* entry point of the game 
*/ 
function run(){ 
init(); 
int = setInterval(gameLoop, interval); 
} 

function init(){ 
createMap(); 
createSnake(); 
createFruit(); 
} 

/** 
* Generates the map for the snake 
*/ 
function createMap(){ 
document.write("<table>"); 

for( var y = 0; y < height; y++){ 
    document.write("<tr>"); 
    for( var x = 0; x < width; x++){ 
        if(x == 0 || x == width -1 || y == 0 || y == height -1){ 
            document.write("<td class='wall' id='"+ x + "-" + y +"'></td>"); 
        }else{ 
            document.write("<td class='blank' id='"+ x + "-" + y +"'>
</td>"); 
        } 
    } 
    document.write("</tr>"); 
} 

document.write("</table>"); 

} 



function createSnake(){ 
set(snakeX, snakeY, "snake"); 
} 

function get(x,y){ 
return document.getElementById(x+"-"+y); 
} 

function set(x,y,value){ 
if(x != null && y != null) 
    get(x,y).setAttribute("class", value); 
} 

function rand(min,max){ 
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 
} 

function getType(x,y){ 
return get(x,y).getAttribute("class"); 
} 

function createFruit(){ 
var found = false; 
while(!found && (length < (width-2)*(height-2)+1)){ 
    var fruitX = rand(1,width-1); 
    var fruitY = rand(1,height-1); 
    if(getType(fruitX, fruitY) == "blank") 
        found = true; 
} 
set(fruitX, fruitY, "fruit"); 
fX = fruitX; 
fY = fruitY; 
} 

/** 
 * NOTE: notice use of new variable tempdir 
 */ 
window.addEventListener("keypress", function key(event){ 
//if key is W set direction up 
var key = event.keyCode; 
if(direction != -1 && (key == 119 || key == 87)) 
    tempdir = 0; 
//if key is S set direction down 
else if(direction != 0 && (key == 115 || key == 83)) 
    tempdir = -1; 
//if key is A set direction left 
else if(direction != 2 && (key == 97 || key == 65)) 
    tempdir = 1; 
//if key is D set direction right 
else if(direction != 1 && (key == 100 || key == 68)) 
    tempdir = 2; 
if(!running) 
    running = true; 
else if(key == 32) 
    running = false; 
}); 

function gameLoop(){ 
if(running && !gameOver){ 
    update(); 
}else if(gameOver){ 
    clearInterval(int); 
} 
} 

/** 
 * NOTE: notice use of new variable tempdir 
 */ 
function update(){ 
direction = tempdir; 
//prevents fruit from not showing up 
set(fX, fY, "fruit"); 
//update the tail 
updateTail(); 
//sets the last segment of the tail to blank  before moving the snake 
set(tailX[length], tailY[length], "blank"); 
//updates the position of the snake according to the direction 
if(direction == 0) 
    snakeY--; 
else if(direction == -1) 
    snakeY++; 
else if(direction == 1) 
    snakeX--; 
else if(direction == 2) 
    snakeX++; 
//draws the head of the snake on the tail 
set(snakeX, snakeY, "snake"); 
//checks for collisions with self 
for(var i = tailX.length-1; i >=0; i--){ 
    if(snakeX == tailX[i] && snakeY == tailY[i]){ 
        gameOver = true; 
        break; 
    } 
} 
//checks for collision with wall 
if(snakeX == 0 || snakeX == width-1 || snakeY == 0 || snakeY == height-1) 
    gameOver = true; 
//checks for collisions with fruit 
else if(snakeX == fX && snakeY == fY){ 
    //adds 1 to the score 
    score+=1; 
    //creates new fruit, which automatically replaces the old one 
    createFruit(); 
    //adds the set increment to the length of the snake making it longer 
    length+=increment; 
} 
//set 
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: "+ score; 
} 

function updateTail(){ 
for(var i = length; i > 0; i--){ 
    tailX[i] = tailX[i-1]; 
    tailY[i] = tailY[i-1]; 
} 
tailX[0] = snakeX; 
tailY[0] = snakeY; 
} 


run();
```

The Codepen

https://codepen.io/McComb/pen/EoYVRY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what requirements you have for this project, but i added jQuery to ease my work in it.

i added a new div in the body

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

i changed your createMap method with this :

```
/**
 * Generates the map for the snake
 */
function createMap(){

    var canvas;

    canvas = '<table>';
    for( var y = 0; y < height; y++){
        canvas += "<tr>";
        for( var x = 0; x < width; x++){
            if(x == 0 || x == width -1 || y == 0 || y == height -1){
                canvas +=  "<td class='wall' id='"+ x + "-" + y +"'></td>";
            }else{
                canvas += "<td class='blank' id='"+ x + "-" + y +"'></td>";
            }
        }
        canvas += "</tr>" ;
    }

    $('#canvas').html(canvas);

}
```

and added a reset method

```
function reset()
{

    //settings
     snakeX = 2;
     snakeY = 2;
     height = 28;
     width = 50;
     interval = 100;
     increment = 1;

    //game variables
     length = 0;
     tailX = [snakeX];
     tailY = [snakeY];

     running = false;
     gameOver = false;
     direction = -1; // up = 0, down = -1, left = 1, right = 2

     score = 0;
    //temporary direction (this fixes users pressing keys too quickly and turning into themselves)
     tempdir = direction;

    clearInterval(int);
    run();

    // reset score
    $('#score').text('Score: '+score);

}
```

here is the project with the changes :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vpBKyL